# Recognize the celestial object in UMa

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing

I’m new to Astronomy observations. I took a picture from my phone of a object near beta Ursa Major and m97 which I couldn’t find (I was on low magnification), I couldn’t find out what it was. Any ideas of what it was (or is it due to my telescope being set up incorrectly)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how long you exposed the image.

However the image looks like a shot of maybe a second or so through the eye piece. Then most likely explanation is you see the somewhat blurred image of $\beta$ UMa, and nothing else due to the too short exposure time.

Galaxies don't need high resolution to be detected (they are MUCH bigger than stars. The galaxies in the Messier catalogue typically are comparable to the size of the full moon), but it needs high sensitivity and / or long exposure times.